# Javascript, Finding largest number sequence in a String

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

In Javascript, I'm trying to make a function which will find the longest number in a string and convert it to a floating point value. However, when I input something like `ff333sds22442`, it will output "333" as the longest number when it should output `22442`.

```
<input type="text" id="numberInput"></input>
<button onclick="findNumber()"> Find Number </button>
<button onclick="makeSubstring()"> Make Substring </button>
<p id="number"></p>

<script>

function findNumber() {
     var input = document.getElementById("numberInput").value;
     var longest = "";
     var result = "";
     var inputSub = "";

     for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
         for (var j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {

             inputSub = input.substring(i, j + 1);
             if (!isNaN(parseFloat(inputSub)) && inputSub.length > longest.length){
                longest = inputSub;
                result = inputSub;
             }
         }
     }

     result = parseFloat(result);
     document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = result;
}
```

I'm not sure why it's doing this, I was hoping someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Aside from being not very efficient to start with, when you compare `inputSub.length` you are comparing the length of the substring, not the length of the *parsed* float. So result will always end up being the original string (because it's the longest). And `parseFloat` on that will give you the first number it finds (namely `333`)

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to sort through this that I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work properly is that you are testing to see if `parseFloat(inputSub)` is `NaN`. This doesn't work because `parseFloat('333sds')` will return 333, not `NaN`.

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for `parseFloat` contains a stricter parse function that you could use to fix the bug in your function:

```
var filterFloat = function (value) {
    if(/^(\-|\+)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|Infinity)$/
      .test(value))
      return Number(value);
  return NaN;
}

console.log(filterFloat('421'));               // 421
console.log(filterFloat('-421'));              // -421
console.log(filterFloat('+421'));              // 421
console.log(filterFloat('Infinity'));          // Infinity
console.log(filterFloat('1.61803398875'));     // 1.61803398875
console.log(filterFloat('421e+0'));            // NaN
console.log(filterFloat('421hop'));            // NaN
console.log(filterFloat('hop1.61803398875'));  // NaN
```

Comment: No problem. I just added an edit to my answer with something that may help you solve the problem, and it introduces you to regular expressions, if you haven't encountered those yet.

Comment: I haven't encountered regular expressions yet. I hope you aren't talking about the if statement in there, because that looks nasty and I don't want to encounter that again anytime soon.

Comment: Welcome to regular expressions :) They are not easy to read, but they are very powerful, and once you get the hang of them, you will find a lot of uses for them. Try out a tutorial (e.g., http://javascript.info/tutorial/regular-expressions-javascript), and it won't seem so bad.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm new here and it's really reassuring that someone is willing to reach out and help me so much!

Comment: No problem. If you want to pay me back, click the checkbox next to my answer. That let's everyone know that my answer was what you were looking for. If you're feeling particularly generous, you can also click the up arrow (that will give me 10 extra points :)).

Comment: Apparently I can't vote up yet, I need more reputation for that. :/